What is the correct way to avoid buffer overflow warning for PC-Lint
How to fix warning - Unbound scanf conversion. This is how I am trying to fix this:
void Class::func1(
    const string &item_as_string,
    unsigned int &unit_id,
    unsigned int &subprogam_id,
    string &slotDescription
)
{
   string bitset_flags;
   const char *line_pointer = item_as_string.c_str();
   unsigned int i, length = item_as_string.length();
   
   unit_id = 0;
   subprogram_id = 0;
   slotDescription = "";
   valid_line = false;

   boost::scoped_array<char> flags( new char[length+1] );
   flags[0]=0;

   boost::scoped_array<char> slotDescriptionPtr( new char[length+1] );
   slotDescriptionPtr[0]=0;

   int val;
   // QString pattern("%u,%u %1%s %1%s");
   val = sscanf ( line_pointer, QString("%u,%u %1%s %2%s").arg(length+1).arg(length+1).toStdString().c_str(),
                 &unit_id, &subprogram_id, flags.get(), slotDescriptionPtr.get() );
}

I need help in this line of code :
val = sscanf ( line_pointer, QString("%u,%u %1%s %2%s").arg(length+1).arg(length+1).toStdString().c_str(),
                 &unit_id, &subprogram_id, flags.get(), slotDescriptionPtr.get() );


The simplest way would be to use c++ functions for string parsing rather than scanf

You seem to have a very weird mix of frameworks you're using. Besides the standard C++ function, I'm sure that Qt have a lot itself to help you. Both which will help you without the use of pointers or dynamic memory allocations.

Correct way would be to use C++ standard library instead of C functions:
int main() {
    std::string item_as_string = "12 34 someText someText2";
    unsigned int unit_id{0};
    unsigned int subprogam_id{0};
    std::string flags;
    std::string desc;
    std::stringstream ss{item_as_string};
    ss >> unit_id;
    ss >> subprogam_id;
    ss >> flags;
    ss >> desc;
    std::cout << unit_id << ", " << subprogam_id << ", " << flags << ", " << desc << std::endl;
}

You can check the result of each operation with
if (ss) { /* all good */ }
else { /* sth wrong */ }

And if for some reason you really care about max number of characters in your flags and desc, you can just trim them later. Or you can use setw e.g.: ss >> std::setw(length+1) >> flags;, but be aware that unread characters will be left in the stream.

I wouldn't call doing basic error checking "being pedantic"
